# CIN not refreshing?

Tags: c++

First of all I know the question title is not clear, thus, let me explain my issue.

I am writing a cpp code where I use std::cin, it is supposed to check if the input is or is not a number and if it is negative or positive.

Here is my code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    SetConsoleTitle(" ");
    while(true) {
        int x;
        if((cin >> x)) {
            cin.ignore();
            if(x > 0) {
                cout << "Podmienka splnena\n";
            }else{
                cout << "Podmienka nesplnena\n";
            }   
        }else{
            cin.ignore();
            cout << "Neplatny vstup\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The issue I am having is that it seems that cin does not accept any new input in case the input was not a number, which is pretty odd, what happens is that it will keep going on and on with the previous input, I hope I was pretty clear.

Comment: The best way to validate input is to read the whole line as text, and then attempt to validate the contents (for example by using `std::stoi` to attempt to convert to an integer, with built-in validation).

Comment: I think you may have confused `ignore` with `clear`.

Comment: @vll Yeah, I found useful information there, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **problem** is the you don't clear the **failbit** from the stream. This can be done with the clear function. So the correct way would be:

```
else{
           
        cout << "Neplatny vstup\n";
        cin.clear();//clear the error flag
        cin.ignore();
        }
```

#### Alternative Solution

Note that you can also do this **without** using `cin.ignore`, `cin.ignore` as shown below. The below example takes the input as `std::string` and then does the validation.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main(void) {
    std::string input;
    int x;
    while(std::getline(std::cin,input)) {
        std::istringstream ss(input);
        if((ss >> x)) {
          
            if(x > 0) {
                std::cout << "Podmienka splnena\n";
            }else{
                std::cout << "Podmienka nesplnena\n";
            }   
        }else{
           
            std::cout << "Neplatny vstup\n";
             
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When input fails, `cin` enter a failed state (can be tested by `cin.fail()`). After removing the bad input, you need to call `cin.clear()` to reset the state.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I have been looking for, I have tried some of those functions (cin.ignore() and cin.clear()) but I was not aware they had to be used together and In a specific order

Comment: Note that you should call `cin.clear()` *before* calling `cin.ignore()` ... and you don't need to call the `ignore` after a successful read.